# Any way to manage a LinkedIn Ads account through multiple users?

Tags: linkedin, ads

Is there any way to grant multiple users the permission to administrate a **LinkedIn Ads** account? It would be very handy to monitor complex campaigns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A business account allows you to separate ads, campaign settings, and billing information from your personal LinkedIn account and share access to this account with others. You can also assign other members to various roles on the account:

- Standard User
- Viewer
- Admin
- Billing Contact
- Campaign Contact